Robotic Dog Kinematics & RVIZ
I am working on a summer project involving creating quadruped robot. I am in the process of creating a simple walking gait, to which I have fundamental understanding of the inverse kinematics. I am using RVIZ to visually simulate how the joints are moving and was wondering what is the best way to go about this.
I watched a video on kinematics relating to a very similar project and will apply cosine law in order to adjust the angle to move the servos so that C is the desired length. I am curious as how can I do this because I don't have a relative coordinate system to tell me the distance to where the end of link_2 sits versus the very top (ie I don't know what C is to begin with so I don't know what is a good value to select to move the leg upwards). I know A and B as they're definedby cad software, so I guess I could calculate C and go from there but I just wanted to get advice from others to see if my head is in the right spot.
Thanks.

